# Set class to active and remove it when another menu item is selected bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tested out the script below in jsfiddle and it works fine, can someone guide me how to fix it? This is the url that I need it working in, the wizard style menu at the top right should should have each item set to active when clicked and then removed when another menu item is clicked: http://morxmedia.com/clients/temp/45p/index_vertical.html

Here is the code I am using for this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.wizard-steps div').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: given link does not add `active` class to any div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(function() {
    $('.wizard-steps div').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried yours and all of the others, yours is the only one that worked copy and paste but thanks everyone :)!!

Answer (score 3):

You are binding the click event to `div` elements when you should bind them to `a` elements like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wizard-steps > div > a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

better to include that on a ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.wizard-steps div').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see (in your CSS). The class `active` should go on the div under `wizard-steps` and the parent of the `a`-tag.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.wizard-steps div a').click(function(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault)
        e.preventDefault();
    else
        e.stop();

    $('.wizard-steps div').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in another way using jquery using `.not()`

**Jquery Code:**

```
$('.wizard-steps div').click(function() {
          $('.wizard-steps div').not(this).removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/PLbbr/